# SQL CE & Dataset - Row does not exist

Tags: c#, dataset, sql-server-ce, asp.net-3.5

I'm (new to and) working with a SQL CE database that will later be connected to a project where we send and receive information to a device over a SerialPort. This database will store information about every part of the communication. I'm a little stuck when it comes to updating a Dataset and committing this updated data to the database.

```
data = new DataSet();
adapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + [table_name])
builder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(adapter);
adapter.Fill(data, [table_name]);

data.Tables[table_name].Rows[identity_value][a_column] = a_column_value;
adapter.Update(data, [table_name]);
```

Before I run this method I'm ensuring that I have a record in the table at identity value 1. However I'm getting a `There is no row at position 1` IndexOutOfRangeException before I call the adapter.Update(). I'm assuming that I've misunderstood how to use and update a Dataset. Any advice?

I've tried looking into the Dataset prior to trying to update the row however the debugger doesn't seem to let me peer into the Dataset, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Using DataSet is not the most performant way to access SQL Server Compact

Comment: I think you will need to call builder.GetInsertCommand(), builder.GetUpdateCommand(), builder.GetDeleteCommand(), before you attempt to update the Data Adapter.

Comment: It was not my design decision however what would you recommend?

Comment: Read up on those commands to call and while I agree they seems beneficial it didn't actually seem to help in this instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var rows = data.Tables[table_name].Select(String.Format("[Id] = {0}",identity_value));

if (rows.Length == 1)
{
    rows[0][a_column] = a_column_value;
}
```

you are interpreting wrong the property `Rows`

```
data.Tables[table_name].Rows[ROWINDEX][COLUMNINDEX]
```

ROWINDEX is the array index not the identity

A suggestion:

if you have to use `DataSet` then load table schema info too with [SqlCeDataAdapter.FillSchema](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlcedataadapter.fillschema%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
adapter.FillSchema(data.Tables[table_name], SchemaType.Mapped);
```

`adapter.Fill(data, [table_name]);` this loads only the data:

Then if you have at least one column designated as a primary key column in the `DataTable` you can get the row with [DataRowCollection.Find Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydd48eyk.aspx):

```
DataRow foundRow = data.Tables[table_name].Rows.Find(identity_value);
```

Comment: Thank you for a solution (works!), just wondering if you can explain to me what the problem with my attempt was?

Comment: @SimonJohnson added in answer

Comment: So there is no (elegant) way to directly grab a row inside a Dataset (by the identity field of the row) and modify some of the data?

Comment: Using the same table name for both of the adapter fills but the adapter.FillSchema() claims the dataTable is null?

`data = new DataSet();
adapter = new SqlCeAdapter("SELECT * FROM [table_name] WHERE [table_identity]=" + tableIdentiity, connection)
builder = new SqlCeBuilder(adapter)
adapter.FillSchema(data.Table[table_name], SchemaType.Mapped);

Comment: @SimonJohnson                     dataSet.Tables.Add(new DataTable(tableName));
                    sqlCeDataAdapter.FillSchema(dataSet.Tables[tableName], SchemaType.Mapped);
                    sqlCeDataAdapter.Fill(dataSet.Tables[tableName]);